# How to make a recursive onClickListener for expanding and collapsing?

Tags: java, android

In plain english, I have a textview, and when I click on it I want it to expand, and when I click on it again, I want it to compress. How can I do this? I've tried the below, but it warns on the final line about expander might not be initialized on holderFinal.text.setOnClickListener(expander);

So now the code:

```
final View.OnClickListener expander = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    holderFinal.text.setText(textData);
    holderFinal.text.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {                                    
        holderFinal.text.setText(shortText);
        holderFinal.text.setOnClickListener(expander);
      }
    });
 }
};
```

Comment: probably replace expander with "this"

Comment: DUH!!! Well this got me further, but not it expands, collapses, and then refuses to expand....more debugging

Comment: Wait....this means the inner one so how do I get the outer listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use nested overrides if you can use the tag property:

```
const int COLLAPSED = 0;
const int EXPANDED = 1;
// set initial value(s) somewhere
holderFinal.setTag(COLLAPSED);
holderFinal.text.setText(shortText);


holderFinal.text.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {       
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = (int)holderFinal.getTag();
    if (i == EXPANDED)
    {
      holderFinal.setTag(COLLAPSED);
      holderFinal.text.setText(shortText);
    }
    else
    {
      holderFinal.setTag(EXPANDED);
      holderFinal.text.setText(textData);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Coulnd't you just find out if you're in a compressed or expanded state? If so, just go with

```
final View.OnClickListener expander = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if(inCompressedState(v){
        holderFinal.text.setText(textData);
    }else{
        holderFinal.text.setText(shortText);
    }
  }
};
```

or something like that :)

Comment: This code would not compile: new View.OnClickListener() {       
    }else{

Comment: Haha, i've just typed it quicky, there's bound to be some } and ( missing, if you can't debug it i'll give it a check, but it's the idea i was offering...

Comment: hows that? fixed some of the stuff

Comment: You obviously need an inCompressedState method here. Instead of a method just use a member variable.

Comment: I have the solution posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

    `holder.text.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final View.OnClickListener ref = this;
                    holderFinal.text.setText(textData);
                    holderFinal.text.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            holderFinal.text.setText(shortText);
                            holderFinal.text.setOnClickListener(ref);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });`